# In Unity Editor , Firebase Authorization 'SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync' fails after restricting API key to Android apps

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Im working with a Unity project and using Firebase SDK.
In Firebase Console , For the default firebase created API keys , I set the application restriction to android apps and mentioned the package name and SHA-1 value.
After restricting the key , I'm trying to authenticate using the method "SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync" by passing email and password.
But authentication fails and the the task is faulted.

I checked the google-services.json file and also enabled the keystore settings under Unity publishing settings. All looks fine. But still authentication fails.

When i removed the restriction that is set to API key , Authentication is successful.

But i have to set the restriction and also the authentication should not fail.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Just to check, how are you ensuring it is restricted to Android Apps? Are you using a condition that depends on the app config (and restricting this to ones on Android) or some other method?

Comment: @JoeSpiro I'm restricting to android apps via google cloud console.
in GCP , under 'API and Credentials' section , we have to select the default created API keys and set the restriction to Android using package name and SHA 1 value.

After making this restriction , Authentication fails when playing the app in Unity editor.